# How to Upload two different format files to two different file paths using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stream, asp.net-web-api

My client app will be sending me an image file and a video file through Multi part form data stream. And i want to store the image file in image folder and the video file in the video folder.

This is how the request from the client looks like

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Photo"; filename="IMG_9322.JPG"
Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Video"; filename="sample.avi"
Content-Type:application/octet-stream

And this is the Api controller method at my end

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UploadVideoEntry")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadVideoEntry()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var folderName = "photos";
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {               

            // Read the form data and return an async task.
            var response = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);              


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseMessage<Object> { success = true, message = "Media Uploaded" });

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

This stores both the files in the photo folder because thats the path i have given. But i dont know how i can separate both the files and store them in different paths. Please let me know if anyone has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples on the following page:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

You want to get the file names after the files are downloaded and move them.  I have done something very similar.  Once you have the filename you can use

```
File.Move(currentPath,newPath)
```

to move the file to the new location.  Your currentPath is your `root` variable plus the filename.  Don't forget to add the @"\" as such:

```
currentPath = root + @"\" + filename
```

Below is code for getting the file name.

```
foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
    Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
}
```

My own first step would be to test the filename to determine the extension and then perform whatever action you want, in this case a move, once you find the appropriate file.